# Could not connect to SMTP host - failed to verify certificate

Tags: php, wordpress, email, ssl, smtp

I have following situation:

Server 1: Windows server with email server. Server address pattern: `mail.myservers.com`

Server 2: Ubuntu 20 (fresh instal month ago) with lsws web server, without email server. Server address pattern: `s2.myservers.com`

Server 2 is used for hosting PHP apps. Few days ago I installed brand new wordpress web. Since server 2 is not having email server then sendmail is simply not working. All sites have to use workaround via SMTP server like wordpress uses PHPMailer.

Web hosted on server 2 using address pattern `myproject.com`. While I am trying to test SMTP from wordpress administration I am getting following error.

```
Versions:
WordPress: 5.7.2
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 8.0.2
WP Mail SMTP: 2.8.0

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Host: mail.myservers.com
Port: 587
SMTPSecure: tls
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(true)
SMTPAuth: bool(true)

Server:
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1f 31 Mar 2020
Apache.mod_security: No

Debug:
Mailer: Ostatní SMTP
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

SMTP Debug:
2021-06-01 16:30:46 Connection: opening to mail.myservers.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()

2021-06-01 16:30:46 Connection: opened

2021-06-01 16:30:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mail.myservers.com ESMTP

2021-06-01 16:30:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO myproject.com

2021-06-01 16:30:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mail.myservers.com250-SIZE 30720000250-STARTTLS250-AUTH LOGIN250 HELP

2021-06-01 16:30:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

2021-06-01 16:30:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 Ready to start TLS

2021-06-01 16:30:46 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [/home/myproject.com/public_html/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php line 467]

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

2021-06-01 16:30:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2021-06-01 16:30:46

2021-06-01 16:30:46

2021-06-01 16:30:46 Connection: closed

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

I run email server for 4 years on LetsEncrypt cert. I had no problem ever since. My guess is something is wrongly configured on ubuntu server.

I read few topics including PHPMailer troubleshooting steps:

- Ubuntu time is synchronized
- PHPMailer troubleshooting cert verify failing

1. My guess is this is for wrong PHP version (7.2). Web is using 8.0 so I edited conf to path below

> ```
> php -i | grep cafile
> openssl.cafile => no value => no value
> ```
>
> curl.cainfo =/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt,
> openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

2. `echo QUIT | openssl s_client -crlf -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587` returns ok
3. Checked certificates for `mail.myservers.com s2.myservers.com myproject.com` via external service. Returns ok
4. hosts

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 s2.myservers.com s2
> 127.0.0.1 s2
>
> .. ipv6 loopbacks
> ```

I ran out of ideas.

EDIT:
miken reply

```
subject=C = US, O = IdenTrust, CN = IdenTrust Commercial Root CA 1
subject=C = US, O = IdenTrust, CN = IdenTrust Public Sector Root CA 1
```

Steffen reply

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.myservers.com:587 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = mail.myservers.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mail.myservers.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = mail.myservers.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = mail.myservers.com
```

Comment: Do you have a certificate bundle at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`? Does it contain the CA for the server you're connecting to? Did you restart your web server after making changes to the `php.ini` file?

Comment: @miken32 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt file exists. I can see in linux there is a lot of certificates in. However if I download it to windows I can see just one. How can I check it? Edit: lsws was rebooted after changes

Comment: *"I run email server for 4 years on LetsEncrypt cert."* - really the __mail__ server? Because configuration and likely also certificates are different from the __web__ server. *"I had no problem ever since."* - this means you can use SMTP (mail) with TLS from other systems with full certificate validation, only not from this particular one?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yep, it can sound weird however I am using LetsEncrypt for mail server. Generating new cert every 14 days. I am using connection from iOS and windows clients. Yet I have to admit never tried before using unix. I changed for few moments sending via google smtp - it works. Long time ago (e.g. 1 year) I hosted wordpress on server 1, using smtp worked.

Comment: To view certificates in bundle, use `openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout | grep ^subject`

Comment: @user1085907: Can you do a `openssl s_client -connect ... -smtp starttls` against your own server (not smtp.gmail.com) and include the output into your question, especially the first part which shows the certificates provided?  *"Checked certificates for mail.myservers.com s2.myservers.com myproject.com via external service."* - did this really check the mail server on port 587 and not the web server? Must services only check the web server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Included into post. It looks like we found an issue. Email server is hMailServer which uses .private and .public key. I export them via C# based program. Certificate is generated by Certify the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:  The certificate chain returned by the server is missing an important intermediate certificate. Without this the leaf certificate of the server can not be checked against the trust store. That's why validation fails.

In detail: The full certificate chain returned by the mail server is this:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = mail.myservers.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
```

From this output can be seen that the server only returns the leaf certificate with the subject of the server, which is issued by *R3*. It does not return the intermediate certificate for *R3* which is issued by *ISRG Root X1*. But the root certificate is *ISRG Root X1* and only this root certificate is in the trust store. See also [Let's Encrypt Certificate Hierarchy 2021](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/).

The fix need to be done at the server side, i.e. the full chain with leaf certificate and intermediate certificate should be provided by the server. Since hMailServer is used see also [this documentation](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_sslcertificates) which explicitly states: *"This certificate should contain the trust chain (Root CA and any **Intermediary Certificates**), in addition to the Server Certificate"*. While some applications might work around missing certificates or some simply ignore certificate errors, this is still a server side problem.

Alternatively the problem can be worked around at the client side by importing the missing intermediate certificate into the client side trust store.

Comment: I can confirm this is correct solution. As soon as I added root + intermediate cert into public key file and restarted service its working! Thank you so much for guiding me.